# Is there a way to accurately generate an evenly-spaced array? numpy.arange() gives me inexact results

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to generate an evenly spaced array which needs to be very precise. A specific example would be an array from 690.4025 to 3968.85, in steps of exactly 1.9285.

Using numpy.arange() with floats results in an array which does not end at 3968.85, and there's some sort of weird systematic drift away from the "true" values of such an array.

How would you generate this kind of data if precision down to about 0.0001 is required for each value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @not_a_robot: No, that's an entirely unrelated question.

Comment: Nate, there's an inconsistency in your question: where does 567.89 come from?

Comment: What do you mean "end at 567.89"? This number is not in the interval "690.4025 to 3968.85".

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.linspace()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to generate an array whose last element is exactly what you specify. In your example,

```
linspace(690.4025, 3968.85, (3968.85-690.4025)/1.9285)
```

should do it. Of course, some of the intermediate values may not be exactly representable as floating point numbers, so they might be inexact, but there's no way around that. If you're using 64-bit floats, the inaccuracy is on the order of 10<sup>-15</sup> so it should still be within your tolerance.

Comment: And even when the intermediates are exactly representable, [you can still get rounding errors](http://ideone.com/d9VwBi).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you could just create an int array and then divide:

```
a = np.arange(6904025, 39688500, 19285) / 10000
```

also, to be clear, the original way you did has a total error on the order of 10^-8 (i.e., summing up all the differences between the int way and the float way), so that way should be more than precise enough.

Comment: Thanks. What I was missing seems to be that arange gives an array *up to but not including* the specified value, which inflated the "error".

Comment: yeah, it's like that for almost all ranges in python, except for maybe some pandas stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) is designed for this task:

```
numpy.linspace(690.4025, 3968.85, num=whatever)
```

where `num` should be the number of elements you want in your array (including the endpoints), rather than the step size.

Answer (score 0):

`690.4025+1700*1.9285=3968.8525`. So your start,stop,step seems to be irrelevant.

probably `arange(690.4025,3969,1.9285)` is what you want ?

```
[  690.4025,   692.331 ,   694.2595, ...,  3964.9955,  3966.924 ,
    3968.8525]
```